# "Mixed integer class inputs are not supported" Error

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am working on a project in Matlab and i have to use the [gradient](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html) function. Following is my code snippet:

`im=imread('A.jpg'); //Reads image File
[Ix,Iy]=gradient(rgb2gray(im));`

I am Getting the Following error.

> Error using bsxfun
>
> Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.
>
> Error in gradient (line 68)
>
> g(2:n-1,:) = bsxfun(@rdivide,(f(3:n,:)-f(1:n-2,:)),h);

I am not able to understand why this error is showing up and how to resolve it.

PS: I know there are many questions posted related to same error but they are due to different causes. I have gone through them but am not to solve my problem.

Comment: Try `imgradient`, it supports integer data types.

Answer (score 4):

1. load an image.
2. Use rgb2grey if necessary.
3. Use im2double
4. Use gradient function, i.e., [fx,fy]=gradient(image)
5. Use matlab function quiver(fx,fy) to get the result displayed.

Ahsan Latif

Answer (score 1):

You should try `[Ix, Iy] = gradient(double(rgb2gray(A)))`. Or alternatively, as Daniel suggests, use `imgradient`.

Comment: Converting images using `double` causes problems because the rescaling to 0..1 range is not done. Most im* function expect double images to be in the 0..1 range, use `im2double` instead to convert an image to double.